# Does Yoroi support the gateway-like features of Metamask?

Tags: yoroi

A really powerful feature of Metamask is that websites can easily use it to connect your wallet - i.e. uniswap, sushiswap, and so on. Does Yoroi support a similar feature?

If not, are there other tools that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Yoroi doesn't interact with Metamask. However, Yoroi does have this functionality in development-as I understand it.

[Here is a clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_Ckst_vAJk) of one its developers speaking on this matter.